# Get all objects from one Parse class that are not mentioned in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm trying to query all records from `confessions` class whose `author` is not `[PFUser currentUser]`... but only those that our `[PFUser currentUser]` didn't rate on in `ratings` class.

`confessions` class:

[image]

`ratings` class:
[image]

Basically, I want to connect these two queries into one (somehow):

```
// get all confessions from other users
PFQuery *qConfessions = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"confessions"];
[qConfessions whereKey:@"author" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

// get all ratings from this user
PFQuery *qRatings = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ratings"];
[qRatings whereKey:@"ratedBy" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

// get all qConfessions that are not in qRatings.confession
// YOUR HELP HERE :)
```

If there is no easy way to achieve what I want, do you think I should change the model and how? Should I just fetch all the ratings and then somehow ignore all `qConfessions` that are equal to `ratings.confession`? Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: So your using the rating class as a join table only? Why aren't you using a relationship?

Comment: @Wain I thought pointer was some kind of a relationship. This is the first time I'm using Parse for something more than just storing objects so I guess I'll have to dig deeper into the documentation :) I'm used to writing SQL so I need to change the way I think. Thanks

Comment: It is, buy you have a class with just 2 pointers, that whole thing should be a relationship

Comment: I made it work with the current data model (take a look at my answer)... if you have time to describe, I would love to see what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a workaround by adding a `confessionId` field to `ratings` class on Parse and using the following code:

```
// get all ratings from this user
PFQuery *qRatings = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ratings"];
[qRatings whereKey:@"ratedBy" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

// get all confessions from other users
PFQuery *qConfessions = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"confessions"];
[qConfessions whereKey:@"author" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

// only fetch confessions that are not rated by current user
[qConfessions whereKey:@"objectId" doesNotMatchKey:@"confessionId" inQuery:qRatings];

// get all confessions from other users that are not rated by current user 
[qConfessions findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // Success
    } else {
        // Error
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// get all qConfessions that are not in qRatings.confession
[qRatings whereKey:@"confession" doesNotMatchQuery: qConfessions];
[qRatings findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
    } esle {
    }
}];
```

Comment: I need confessions that are not mentioned in ratings. Your example loads all ratings that don't match the confessions query. Thank you for trying.